# any way to store data locally in an HTML5 application, and access it from any installed browser?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, web-storage

`Indexeddb` is the way to go for a reliable option to store big amounts of  data just in the browser. But one limitation of this is that the data stored in one browser(e.g Chrome) is locked there, and cannot be accessed from another browser(e.g Firefox). So if I open my application in Chrome, make some changes (Create some data), and then open this application in Firefox, I will be with a fresh database.

My question is:
 Is there any way to store data locally and make it available to all browsers, without using a backend web service?

Comment: No.. Most people only use one browser anyway, and most services have a persistence layer so this hasn't been discussed before as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

No. All the local storage mechanisms with JS APIs are sandboxed and accessible only to the browser that created them.